# Cordova-pdf-generator: Can't bind image using relative path

Tags: cordova, pdf, ionic-framework, mobile

I am generating `pdf` files using `cordova-pdf-generator` plugin, and I can't bind an image using a relative path.

I have already tried using `file://` protocol and `ng-scr` instead of `src`, but it didn't do the trick.
To make it way more simpler, I did locate both template and image in the same folder.

```
src\assets\template.html
src\assets\logo.png
```

The `HTML` tag looks like:

```
<img ng-src="logo.png" alt="logo" height="40px" />
```

The image would just appear broken in the generated pdf. I guess this is happening because the location of the generated pdf is different from the origin location of the template, but I just can't figure it out which should be the correct path.

Comment: Have you tried using the cdv file protocol? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#cdvfile-protocol

Comment: Image does not show in generated pdf anymore with this plugin in android api 30. https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator/issues/141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access images on a device you will likely need to install `cordova-plugin-file`

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

With the plugin installed you can access via the `cdvfile` protocol.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#cdvfile-protocol

Example from https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator/issues/38

```
 pdf.htmlToPDF({
        data: "<html> <h1>  Hello World  </h1> <img src='cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.png'></html>",
        documentSize: "A4",
        landscape: "portrait",
        type: "share" //use share to open the open-with-menu.
    }, this.success, this.failure);
```